# Converting my Nested Select Statement to an Update Statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-update, dynamics-crm-2011

Here is the current select query I have. I've been trying to update "Final Aging" into a field in a table but I can't seem to figure it out. Also, I've been using `DATEADD` to manually adjust my times to UTC, if someone knew how to rewrite that I'd gladly listen and lear

My current query date diffs two dates and removes weekends and holidays from them. I just need to update the `[FINAL AGING]` but I can't find a way to do it. Any help will be appreciated.

```
    SELECT 
     TICKETNUMBER,
     CONVERT(DATE,CREATEDON),
     CONVERT(DATE,DATEAPPROVED),
     [WITH WEEKEND],
     [WITHOUT WEEKEND],
     [HOLIDAY COUNT],
     [WITHOUT WEEKEND] - [HOLIDAY COUNT] AS [FINAL AGING]
     FROM
     (
      SELECT 
       B.TICKETNUMBER, 
       A.CREATEDON, 
       DATEAPPROVED,
      DATEDIFF(DD, DATEADD(HOUR, 8, A.CREATEDON), DATEADD(HOUR, 8, DATEAPPROVED)) AS [WITH WEEKEND], 
      DATEDIFF(DD, DATEADD(HOUR, 8, A.CREATEDON), DATEADD(HOUR, 8, DATEAPPROVED)) -
      (DATEDIFF(WK, DATEADD(HOUR, 8, A.CREATEDON), DATEADD(HOUR, 8, DATEAPPROVED)) * 2) -
      CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW, DATEADD(HOUR, 8, A.CREATEDON)) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW, DATEADD(HOUR, 8, DATEAPPROVED)) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [WITHOUT WEEKEND],
      (SELECT COUNT(DATE) FROM HOLIDAYMAINTENANCE 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(HOUR, 8, DATE)) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(HOUR, 8, A.CREATEDON))
 AND CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(HOUR, 8, DATEAPPROVED))) AS [HOLIDAY COUNT]
      FROM REQUESTMONITORING A JOIN INCIDENT B ON B.INCIDENTID = A.REQUESTID
      WHERE DATEAPPROVED IS NOT NULL
     ) AS [TABLE]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do the `update` using `join`:

```
with toupdate as (
      <your query here>
     )
update
    set [Final Aging] = toupdate.[Final Aging]
    from TableToUpdate ttu join
         toupdate
         on ttu.TicketNumber = toupdate.TicketNumber;
```

I am guessing that the key for the update is `Final Aging`.  Also, you don't mention the table to update, but you need to join it in -- even if it is the table to define `toupdate`.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response, I have a question about the Join, do I use the same Join as the one in my query? the field I need is inside the REQUESTMONITORING table. I'm sorry for the novice question but I really just put my select statement inside the AS (<query here>)

Comment: I think you would put your `select` in the `with` statement, and then `REQUESTMONITOR` for the `TableToUpdate`.

Comment: That solved it, thank you very much! I would plus rep you but it's my first post.

Comment: Please do not update directly the Dynamics CRM DB. Gordon solution is correct from a SQL side, but for Dynamics CRM update directly the DB is unsupported

Comment: Hi Guido, what do you mean by this?

Comment: @user3540020 means that it is not supported by microsoft (and they will not offer support if you will have problems), if you need to update you need to use crm web services. for example if you have a workflow triggered on the onchange of your age field, when you do a sql update, the workflow will not be triggered